form_tag not triggering patch call in rails
Below is the code to update the statuses for different students but the issue is after I am made some changes to the statues clicking update status does nothing.
students/manage_users.html.erb
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content" role="main" id="main-content">
    <article>
      <div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><%= link_to "Primary Student", :sort => "student_1_firstname" %></th>
                <th>Admin Status</th>
                <th>Superadmin Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <%= form_tag update_status_path, :method => 'patch' do %>
              <tbody>
                <% @students.each do |student| %>
                  <tr> 
                    <td><%= link_to student.email,student_path(student) %></td>

                    <td><%= check_box_tag "students[#{student.id}][admin]", true, student.admin, class: 'status', data: {id: student.id, type: 'admin'} %></td>
                    <td><%= check_box_tag "students[#{student.id}][superadmin]", true, student.superadmin, class: 'status', data: {id: student.id, type: 'superadmin'} %></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <%= submit_tag "Update Status" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
<!-- .content -->
</div>
<!-- END .main_column_css -->

routes.rb
patch 'main-admin/manage_users', to: 'students#update_status', as: 'update_status'

Controller
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def update_status
    @students = Student.all
    students = params[:students]
    @students.each do |student|
      student.update_attributes(admin: students[student.id.to_s] && students[student.id.to_s]['admin'] ? true : false, superadmin: students[student.id.to_s] && students[student.id.to_s]['superadmin'] ? true : false)
    end
  end
end

Please help me fix this

Can you confirm that in your logs?  What route/params/http method does it show when you click the button?

@MarkSwardstrom it doesnt do anything. No request is generated

The problem may be your form tag is in the table tags.  The table body and form closing tag are out of order.  See if fixing that does anything.

you can't nest form element in a table like that. wrap the whole table with a form.

Your HTML is invalid.
According to MDN the permitted contents of a <table> element is restricted to a very narrow set of flow content:
In this order:

 1. an optional <caption> element, 
 2. zero or more <colgroup> elements, 
 3. an optional <thead> element, 
 4. either one of the following: 
    - zero or more <tbody> elements 
    - one or more <tr> elements 
 5. an optional <tfoot>
    element

Forms are not flow content.
You also have mismatched closing tags which just creates a jumble. Move the form tag outside of the table.
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content" role="main" id="main-content">
    <article>
      <div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <%= form_tag update_status_path, method: :patch do %>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><%= link_to "Primary Student", :sort => "student_1_firstname" %></th>
                  <th>Admin Status</th>
                  <th>Superadmin Status</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% @students.each do |student| %>
                <tr> 
                  <td><%= link_to student.email, student_path(student) %></td>
                  <td><%= check_box_tag "students[#{student.id}][admin]", true, student.admin, class: 'status', data: {id: student.id, type: 'admin'} %></td>
                  <td><%= check_box_tag "students[#{student.id}][superadmin]", true, student.superadmin, class: 'status', data: {id: student.id, type: 'superadmin'} %></td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <%= submit_tag "Update Status" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>


On a side note this is a very clunky and naive solution and there are serious faults with how it's implemented. If you're in modern version of Rails it's pretty trivial to use turbo to send ajax requests to update each user invidually from a single form and get direct feedback. This doesn't seem to handle any kind of validation / feedback. What happens when user can't be assigned a role?

When I click on Update Status submit button it is making post request now instead of patch request.
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/main-admin/manage_users
Request Method: POST

If you're looking at the request through the browser inspect that's actually 100% how it's supposed to work. Browsers don't send PUT, PATCH etc. natively so instead you submit a POST request with a _method=PATCH parameter which Rack::MethodOverride uses to override the HTTP method.

When you look at the request in the Rails logs thats after it has passed through the Rack middleware which changes the HTTP method.
